# ember.js Ember.Select value binding with multiple options

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to create a multiple select input element in Ember, where the content is coming from a hash, containing the label, value and group for the different options. This works fine, however I am not able to access the value binding.

[Here is the JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jodoqoponema/1/edit?html,js,console,output); after submitting the form, it logs the selectedField variable to the console which is always 'undefined'.

I would like to implement the binding so that the initial contents of selectedField are preselected.

Update: I now see that the value method is unsupported for multiple selections, but then how do I pre-select and retrieve the selections?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I need to bind the Select via 'selection' (see JSBin).